# Problema ao importar uma classe no Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, request

Estou tentando incluir a classe que faz tratamento da Request do meu formulário, mas o mesmo sempre retorna erro de não encontrado, porém, já verifiquei e reverifiquei e o arquivo e o patch estão correto.

Já tentei fazer update no composer para ver se resolvia, mas sem sucesso, segue o código abaixo.

> Arguments
>   "Class App\Http\Requests\CadastroRequest does not exist"

**Meu arquivo CadastroController.php**

```
<?

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // Banco de dados
    use Request; // Tratamento URI
    use Validator; // Validação
    use App\Cadastro; // Modelo
    use App\Http\Requests\CadastroRequest; // Regras do formulário

    class CadastroController extends Controller {

        // Formulário de Cadastro
        public function cadastro(){

            return view('cadastro.formulario');

        }

        // Registrar Usuário
        public function salvar( CadastroRequest $request ){

            Cadastro::create( $request->all() );
            return redirect('/cadastro/obrigado')->withInput();

        }

    }
?>
```

**Meu arquivo CadastroRequest.php *(root/app/Http/Requests/CadastroRequest.php)***

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class CadastroRequest extends FormRequest { 

        public function authorize() {
            return true; // Manter true para teste
        }

        public function rules() {
            return [
                # Informações de contato
                'nome' => 'required|min:10',
                'email' => 'required|min:10',
                'celular' => 'min:11|max:15',
                # Informações de acesso
                'senha' => 'required|numeric|min:3|max:8',
                'rsenha' => 'required|numeric|min:3|max:8',
                # Informações de endereço
                'estado' => 'required|min:10',
                'cidade' => 'required|min:10',
                'cep' => 'required|min:10',
                'endereco' => 'required|min:10',
                'numero' => 'required|min:10',
                'bairro' => 'required|min:10',

            ];
        }

        public function messages(){

            return [
                'nome.required' => 'Você precisa informar seu nome.'
                'email.required' => 'Insira um e-mail valido, você precisa confirmar o registro.'
                'senha.required' => 'Senha é obrigatória.'
                'rsenha.required' => 'Confirmação da senha é obrigatória.'
                'estado.required' => 'Saber seu estado ajuda a lhe informar jogos acontecendo no seu estado.'
                'cidade.required' => 'Saber a cidade que mora ajuda a lhe informar os jogos próximos a você.'
                'cep.required' => 'Campo CEP é obrigatório.'
                'endereco.required' => 'Campo Endereço é obrigatório.'
                'numero.required' => 'Campo Número é obrigatório.'
                'bairro.required' => 'Campo Bairro é obrigatório.'
            ];

        }
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar `composer dump-autoload` ou adicionar barra invertida antes de incluir a classe `\App\...` ?

Comment: Sim amigo, já tentei adicionar a barra invertida antes do App e rodei o composer dump-autoload, update do composer e cache:clear do artisan, sem sucesso

Comment: Encontrei o problema, na verdade eu achei bizarro! Foi um erro idiota meu de não ter colocado a virgula na função messages(), como fui duplicando a linha eu acabei não percebendo.

A falta dessas virgulas, retornava pra mim que a classe não tinha sido encontrada, quando na verdade, o problema era de pontuação e não que o arquivo da classe não existia.